# Computing hash of a compound key

Tags: hash

Why is the initial value of `hash` 17 and not 0?

```
/**
 * Returns an integer hash code for this date.
 *
 * @return an integer hash code for this date
 */
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 17;
    hash = 31*hash + month;
    hash = 31*hash + day;
    hash = 31*hash + year;
    return hash;
}
```

https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/edu/princeton/cs/algs4/Date.java.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no compelling reason that I'm aware of.  The hash algorithm would also work about as well with an initial value of 0, as far as I can see.

Comment: You are right. The initial value doesn't matter. I tried changing it to 0 and got exactly the same number of collisions.

Also, that hash function isn't very good because it "resets" every 31 years. A better hash function would be `month + 12 * day + 12 * 31 * year`